# I want to include url in bgi statement

Tags: css, sublimetext3, emmet

I'm populating a block of css using emmet, I'm creating a rule using bgi - background image
the code:
`page{bgi}` works and expands to `page{background-image: url();}` which is fine but I would like to include the url in the statement. I've tried `page{bgi:{myimage.gif}}` and `page{bgi:[url(myimage.gif)]}` neither of these works.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've described is currently not supported by `emmet`.

You need to type the value of your `background-image` manually after using `bgi`

The other supported feature from `emmet` for `background-image` property is `bgi:n` which will be converted to `background-image:none;`